# Can you align only a part of the text in a textbox?

Tags: c#

I wanna generate a ranking for teams that are in a list based on their points. How can i format so the names are all aligned left and their points are aligned right in the textbox?

```
//Generating ranking
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            teams = teams.OrderByDescending(o => o.Points).ToList();        
            for (int i = 0; i < teams.Count; i++)
            {
                rankingTextBox.Text += $"{i + 1}.  {teams[i].Name} {teams[i].Points}\n";
            }
        }
```

Now i get this:

1. Team  10
2. secondteam  5
3. thirdTeam  2

But i should be like this without dots:

1. Team.............10
2. secondteam...5
3. thirdTeam.......2

Thank you

Comment: Is this textbox using a fixed-width font? If so you could hack it by inserting spaces, but you should consider a list or grid control instead of a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

this may work:

```
private string SameSize(int Maxsize, string team)
{
        if (team.Length < Maxsize)
            return SameSize(Maxsize, team + ".");
        else
            return team;
}

var maxlength = teams.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name.Length).First().Length + 4;

rankingTextBox.Text += $"{i + 1}.  {SameSize(maxlength,teams[i].Name)} {teams[i].Points}\n";
```

Comment: This might work if I use a font where all characters have the same size I think. Thank you

Comment: This is a rather ugly use of recursion, I'd rewrite it iteratively.